# Is it recommended to return LiveData List in Room DAO

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have DAO like this

```
@Dao
public interface CrewDao {
    // insert, update, delete ...

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Crew")
    Cursor selectAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Crew")
    LiveData<List<Crew>> liveSelectAll();
}
```

Does `LiveData` load all rows in memory? I am afraid if my data grows it will cause OOM error. Should I stick to `Cursor`? Thank you.

Comment: `"Should I stick to Cursor?"` no, use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) library

Comment: and of course use `android.arch.paging.PagedListAdapter`

Comment: How about ```LivePagedListProvider``` ? @pskink

Comment: `LivePagedListProvider` is used with `PagedListAdapter` - see `PagedListAdapter` javadocs